# convent a unsigned 32 bit integer to byte array which length is 4 byte and vice versa in java

Tags: java, numbers

a unsigned 32 bit integer,min is 0,max is The 32 square of 2 minus 1.I want to convent it to byte array which length is 4 byte and  vice versa .
When I run the main method blow,everything is -1?I am so puzzled.
How to get the max from byte array and convent the max to byte array?And other number?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = (long) Math.pow(2, 32);
    l--;
    byte[] bs = toBytes(l);
    for(byte b:bs){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    System.out.println("------");
    byte[] arr = { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xff,(byte) 0xff,(byte) 0xff };
    System.out.println(fromByteArray(arr));

}

static byte[] toBytes(long i)
{
  byte[] result = new byte[4];

  result[0] = (byte) (i >> 24);
  result[1] = (byte) (i >> 16);
  result[2] = (byte) (i >> 8);
  result[3] = (byte) (i /*>> 0*/);

  return result;
}

 static long fromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
     return (bytes[0]& 0xFF) << 24 | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[3] & 0xFF);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're expecting; everything is `-1` because that's how `11111111` is represented in two's-complement binary.

Comment: You could also use a ByteBuffer: use `wrap` to make the buffer then use `putInt` to write it.

Comment: Jacob makes a good point.  If you want to use a special test value, one good way to do it is just assign a hex value directly so you can see the value easily: `long l = 0xA598CBD1;`  You should see those four bytes in the array.  Don't forget to print them as hex values, not decimal ints.

Comment: And for the byte array, just make an empty one, no need to assign values: `byte[] arr = new byte[4];`

Comment: I need the fromByteArray return 4294967295 as Math.pow(2, 32)-1 @JacobG.

Comment: and toBytes can convent the max value to new byte[]{(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff,(byte)0xff} @JacobG.

Comment: sorry,i do not understand two's-complement binary very well,Ｉ will search it by google first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to study how [**two's complement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) works, to understand signed numbers in computers.

But, to showcase the difference between signed and unsigned values, see here:

```
long maxAsLong = 4294967295L; // Unsigned int max value
System.out.println("maxAsLong = " + maxAsLong);

int max = (int) maxAsLong;
System.out.println("max (unsigned) = " + Integer.toUnsignedString(max) +
                                 " = " + Integer.toUnsignedString(max, 16));
System.out.println("max (signed) = " + Integer.toString(max) +
                               " = " + Integer.toString(max, 16));

byte[] maxBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(max).array();
System.out.print("maxBytes (unsigned): ");
for (byte b : maxBytes)
    System.out.print(Byte.toUnsignedInt(b) + " ");
System.out.println();
System.out.print("maxBytes (signed): ");
for (byte b : maxBytes)
    System.out.print(b + " ");
System.out.println();

int max2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).put(maxBytes).rewind().getInt();
System.out.println("max2 (unsigned) = " + Integer.toUnsignedString(max2) +
                                  " = " + Integer.toUnsignedString(max2, 16));
```

*Output*

```
maxAsLong = 4294967295
max (unsigned) = 4294967295 = ffffffff
max (signed) = -1 = -1
maxBytes (unsigned): 255 255 255 255 
maxBytes (signed): -1 -1 -1 -1 
max2 (unsigned) = 4294967295 = ffffffff
```